# How to get QueryList element while using ChnageDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular

Hi I'm in this situation:

the `QueryList` of the following component is always empty and the `changes Observable` never fire,

the component is attached via angular CDK `Overlay` via the color-picker-trigger Directive

> Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-color-picker',
  templateUrl: './color-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./color-picker.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ColorPickerComponent
  implements  AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren(ColorComponent) colorComponents: QueryList<ColorComponent>;

  /* Other stuff */

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.colorComponents); // <---- Empty!

    this.colorComponents.changes.subscribe((ch) => console.log(ch)); <-- never fire!
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }
}
```

> Component Template

```
<ng-template>
  <div
    class="container"
    @picker
    role="grid"
    (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"
    cdkTrapFocus
    cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture
    [style.transformOrigin]="'right top'"
  >
    <div class="row" role="row" *ngFor="let group of groupedColors">
      <app-color
        *ngFor="let color of group"
        (click)="select(color)"
        role="gridcell"
        (keydown)="onGridCellKeyDown($event, color)"
        [attr.tabindex]="color === value ? 0 : -1"
        [isSelected]="color === value"
        [color]="color"
      >
      </app-color>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

`group` is an array of string (HEX Coloros)

> Directive

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[color-picker-trigger]',
  exportAs: 'colorPickerTrigger'
})
export class ColorPickerTriggerDirective {
  private _overlayRef: OverlayRef;

  @Input('color-picker-trigger') colorPicker: ColorPickerComponent;

  constructor(
    public overlay: Overlay,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  ) {}

  private init(): void {
    const overlayConfig: OverlayConfig = new OverlayConfig(<OverlayConfig>{
      hasBackdrop: true,
      backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
    });

    overlayConfig.positionStrategy = this.overlay
      .position()
      .flexibleConnectedTo(this.elementRef)
      .withPositions([
        {
          originX: 'end',
          originY: 'bottom',
          overlayX: 'end',
          overlayY: 'top'
        }
      ]);
    overlayConfig.scrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block();

    this._overlayRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);

    this._overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => this._overlayRef.detach());
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  click(): void {
    if (!this.colorPicker || this.colorPicker.disabled) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this._overlayRef) {
      this.init();
    }

    this.colorPicker.valueChange
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => this._overlayRef.detach());

    this._overlayRef.detach();
    const picker = new TemplatePortal(
      this.colorPicker.template,
      this.viewContainerRef
    );
    this._overlayRef.attach(picker);
  }
}
```

then to use the color-picker

```
      <span>{{color}}</span>
      <button [color-picker-trigger]="colorPicker">clickMe</button>

    <app-color-picker #colorPicker 
[colors]="colors" (valueChange)="color=$event"
></app-color-picker>
```

if I remove the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the Observable fires,

how can I have access to the QueryList while using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: Update the question to show how you are creating the component, and include the `color-picker.component.html` file.

Comment: Ok I'll do it as soon as possible (I'm by mobile now) , but basically it has an ngfor loop over an array of "strings"  which are passed as @Input to each ColorComponent. The picker is generated via a trigger directive